# Tweets Dataframe created using R "twitteR" package has 19 variables in one system and 16 variables in another system

Tags: r, dataframe, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweets

As part of Social Media Analytics,  I have successfully created twitter authentication token and secret keys required to connect to twitter API from R using "twitteR" package. I am able to retrieve tweets using "searchTwitter" function as well.

When I convert the retrieved tweets list into a data frame, I am getting the resultant data frame with 19 variables as shown in the attached screenshot[Tweets dataframe with 19 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN9d6.jpg)

When I run the same set of commands in another system (connected to the same network), the resultant data frame has only 16 variables. The columns "location, language and profileImageURL" are missing from it.

Can anyone please let me know the reason behind this ?

Please note that the R version in both the systems is 3.3.2

**Edited :**
Please find the reproducible code below for your reference

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)

consumer_key="please paste your consumer_key here"
consumer_secret="please paste your consumer_secret key here"
access_token="please paste your access_token here"
access_token_secret="please paste your access_token_secret here"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)

inp_tweets <- searchTwitter("AMZN") ## Retrieve AMZN stock related tweets from twitter

twittDF <- twListToDF(inp_tweets) ## Convert the tweets list into a Dataframe

str(twittDF) ## Display the structure of the Dataframe
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? At least show the code we can run and compare. You don't mention what the systems are.

Comment: what's the `twitteR` versions on both systems? Also, `twitteR` is being deprecated in favour of [`rtweet`](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet)

Comment: Thank you @RomanLuštrik for your response. The "twitteR" version on both the systems is "1.1.9"

Comment: @RomanLuštrik The question is updated to include the reproducible code. Please have a look at it and let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance.